# SetInterval javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagen, slider

escribí este código para unos tótem para mostrar imágenes y logre que todo funcione menos el botón para pausar la reproducción automática...

```
    btnPlay.addEventListener('click', function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        Next();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Ese es el botón de play, y el botón de pausa no tiene nada escrito, intenté varias cosas pero no me han funcionado
Si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradecería mucho!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función `setInterval` devuelve un identificador único que puede usarse para detener la llamada continua de la función usando `clearInterval(identificador)`.

En tu caso específico, para detenerlo, guarda el identificador en una variable fuera de las funciones, y modifícalo con los botones `Play` y `Pause`. Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
let interval;
const btnPlay = document.getElementById('play')
const btnPause = document.getElementById('pause')

btnPlay.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(!interval)
      interval = setInterval(changeColor, 100);
});

btnPause.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(interval)
      clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null
});


function changeColor(){
  const p = document.querySelector('p')
  p.style.color = p.style.color == 'red' ? 'blue': 'red'; 
}
```

```html
<button id="play">Play</button>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>

<p>Prueba</p>
```

Alternativamente usando un solo botón:

```js
let interval;
const btnPlay = document.getElementById('play')

btnPlay.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(!interval){
      interval = setInterval(changeColor, 100);
      btnPlay.innerHTML = "Pause"
      }else{
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null
        btnPlay.innerHTML = "Play"
      }
});


function changeColor(){
  const p = document.querySelector('p')
  p.style.color = p.style.color == 'red' ? 'blue': 'red'; 
}
```

```html
<button id="play">Play</button>

<p>Prueba</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Solo necesitas crear una variable global para poder controlar el intervalo y cancelarlo cuando presiones el botón "Pausa" con [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)

```
// Crear variable global, fuera de funciones
let timer;

// En la función play asignas el intervalo a la variable
btnPlay.addEventListener('click', function(){
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        Next();
    }, 5000);
});

// En la función de pausa cancelas el intervalo
btnPause.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

Sería buena idea cancelar el temporizador antes de iniciarlo, por si se hacen varios clics en el botón Play, para evitar que haya dos o más:

```
btnPlay.addEventListener('click', function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        Next();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Aunque también podrías habilitar y deshabilitar los botones de acuerdo al estado "en reproducción" o "en pausa", pero eso ya es otro tema.