# Imprimir un texto con delay javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero imprimir "si" infinitamente en el documento, con un delay de 1 segundo entre cada "si", solo me imprime el primer "si" que es el que meto a mano

```js
window.onload = function (e) {
    document.write("si");
    setTimeout(() => {
        while (true) {
            document.body.innerHTML += "si<br>";
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [SetInterval javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/490394/setinterval-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo quieres ejecutar por siempre, porque no usas un `setInterval`?

```js
window.onload = function (e) {
    const mostrarSi = () => {
      document.body.innerHTML += "si<br>";
    }

    mostrarSi(); //"Si" inicial
    setInterval(mostrarSi, 1000); //Se programa `mostrarSi` para que se ejecute cada segundo por siempre
}
```

Answer (score 0):

buenas. Se trata de hacer una función que incluya el `setTimeout`, y dentro, llamarla de nuevo para hacer el bucle infinito. Algo así...

```
function inicio() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.innerHTML += "si<br>";

    // Look
    inicio();

    // Cada 1 segundos
    }, 1000);
}

// Inicio del bucle. Se puede llamar directamente al definir el script, al pulsar un botón, en un onLoad, o donde veas.
inicio();
```